# (ES v7.5.1) Speed up snapshot restore from GCS Snapshot Repository

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to speed up our snapshot restoration speed in our ES cluster hosted on GCP Compute instances.

**TL;DR:**

- Current Performance: 56 MBps per data node
- Infra Capable of 500 MBps
- We want to improve our restore speed up to the maximum disk throughput (no throttling from infrastructure).

**Infra Details:**

- 3 Master | 10 Data Nodes
- Each node has 8core/16gb config (heap size: 8gb)
- Each Data instance supports max 15k disk IOPS (500 MBps Throughput)

Current Restore Performance: 4.5 Gbps on the whole cluster (56 MBps per node).

We are currently getting 10% of the total disk write throughput. We are looking for options to improve it.

**Note:** Have already tested any infra-related throttling. Using gsutil -m, we saw the download speed reach to 450 MBps on one of the data nodes.

**What we have already tried:**

- Setting max_restore_bytes_per_sec to 0 in our gcs snapshot repository.
- Setting indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec to 0.

We are unable to figure out the config that is throttling the network performance.

---

**Update:**

We tried to increase the number of data nodes, to check if the throttling is on some data nodes:

Changed Data nodes count from 10 to 20.

**Result:** Speed still throttled at 4.5 Gbps (speed on individual data nodes decreased to half).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple options, we weren't able to find the root cause of this.

We decided to use an updated version of ES (version: 7.10.2).

We are now able to reach 33gbps speed with the updated cluster.

Interestingly, we are using similar configs (similar ansible playbooks) for both the version, but with version 7.10.2, we were able to reach the target speed.